# Style the first few characters of text along a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tikz-path

How can this code be modified so that the first few characters (say 3) are colored red?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,math}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=10,
    decoration={
        text effects along path,
        text={0123456789},
        text effects/.cd,
        character count=\i, character total=\n,
        characters={text along path,
                    evaluate={\c=(\n-\i)+1;},
                    scale=10*\c/\n,
        }
        }
    ]
    \draw[decorate]
          plot (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a good answer ..... But it works.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,math}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=10,
    decoration={
        text effects along path,
        text={{\color{red}0}{\color{red}1}{\color{red}2}3456789},
        text effects/.cd,
        character count=\i, character total=\n,
        characters={text along path,
                    evaluate={\c=(\n-\i)+1;},
                    scale=10*\c/\n,
        }
        }
    ]
    \draw[decorate]
          plot (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The color has to be set for each character.

[image: Result]

Comment: `...     text={0123456789},
        text effects/.cd,
        character count=\i, character total=\n,
        character 1/.style={text={red}},
        character 2/.style={text={red}},
        character 3/.style={text={red}},
        characters={text along path, ...
` moves the styling out from the data, but still hard-codes the character numbers.